# Deploy com GIT via FTP

Tags: git, ftp, bitbucket

Li vários arquivos que é possivel fazer o deploy via FTP usando o GIT. 
Tentei seguir varios deles porem não obtve sucesso.
Sei tb que existem sites que fazem todo este processo de deploy como o [ftploy.com](https://ftploy.com) porém, a nível de conhecimento eu gostaria de aprender a fazer isto na unha.

Estou usando windows e o Git Bash e tenho um repositório no [bitbucket.org](https://bitbucket.org/).
Será que alguem poderia me dar uma luz para fazer isto... pode ser link de estudos ou coisas do genero....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existem várias maneiras de fazer *deploy* utilizando o GIT. Apesar do FTP ser muito utilizado ele [não é muito seguro](http://cpucomputador.blogspot.com.br/2012/10/ftp-porque-e-que-este-protocolo.html) e o GIT [não suporta esse protocolo nativamente](http://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v1/Git-no-Servidor-Os-Protocolos):

> O Git pode usar quatro protocolos principais para transferir dados: Local, Secure Shell (SSH), Git e HTTP.

Geralmente o *deploy* é feito através de SSH, com um *hook* `post-receive` no servidor, [esse tutorial](http://danjesus.github.io/blog/deploy-facil-com-git/) explica detalhadamente a configuração do repositório remoto e dos scripts para *deploy*.

Se você não tem acesso SSH ao servidor, é possível usar o [Git-ftp](http://git-ftp.github.io/git-ftp/), que é um cliente FTP baseado em GIT, é o mais recomendado para esse fim, conforme [essa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23434369) e [essa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4322074) respostas do SOen.

Sites como o ftploy, provavelmente utilizam os *webhooks*, disponíveis em diversos serviços de repositórios GIT como GitHub, GitLab e Bitbucket.

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada como funciona, de qualquer forma vlw.... se der certo algumas das soluções eu volto aqui pra falar qual eu usei..

Comment: Cara..... valeu.... só agora eu pude testar... vida tá corrida. Eu usei o GIT-FTP e deu certo... fiz a instalação no WIN7 com GIT BASH... e usei este turotial http://anantgarg.com/2013/09/25/git-ftp-for-windows/ pra o processo... super fácil é pratico... como é pra fim de estudos não estou preocupado ainda com a segurança. VLW Cara!!!!