# Deploy automático após Git Push

Tags: git, maven, jboss, openshift

Utilizo diariamente o [OpenShift](https://www.openshift.com/) para criar e hospedar aplicações nas nuvens. Uma coisa interessante que observo é quanto ao processo de **deploy** das aplicações hospedadas nesta plataforma. O deploy é antecedido do comando `git push`. Um único e simples comando, sem nenhuma complexidade.

**Existe algum script oculto que realiza os comandos necessários para a realização do processo de deploy ou é algum plugin acoplado ao Maven? Como implementar um processo semelhante a este?**

Comment: Sim, você pode criar scripts que atuam após alguma ação do Git usando Git Hooks. Você pode automatizar muitas coisas com essas ferramentas! [Dá uma olhada nesse ebook em português](http://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v1/Customizando-o-Git-Hooks-do-Git). [Esse outro link também tem um tutorial, em inglês](http://www.sitepoint.com/one-click-app-deployment-server-side-git-hooks/).

Comment: Isso é feito utilizando o *hook* `post-receive`, nesse *script* são inseridos os comandos de `deploy`. Resposta relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/63874/13561

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Supondo que você tem acesso root ao seu servidor, isso é bem fácil de fazer:

Basicamente, você tem que criar um Hook do tipo `post-receive` que vai copiar todo o conteúdo do seu push para um diretório que você determinar e executar o seu build.

Então você tem que ter duas pastas no seu servidor:

- Repositório: `/var/git/meuprojeto.git`
- Seu Projeto: `/var/www/meuprojeto.com`

---

### Criando o Repositório:

```
mkdir /var/git && mkdir /var/git/meuprojeto.git
cd /var/git/meuprojeto.git
git init --bare
```

Você precisa iniciar seu repositório com a opção `--bare`, para que seu repositório não tenha arquivos físicos, apenas o controle de versão. Ou seja, ele é APENAS um repositório.

Os repositórios git possuem uma pasta hooks. Você pode visualizá-la com `ls` e depois entrar nela para criar o seu post-receive:

```
cd hooks && vi post-receive
```

Dentro do vi, aperte a tecla `i` para editar o arquivo e escreva o seguinte conteúdo:

```
#!/bin/sh

meuprojeto=/var/www/meuprojeto.com
git_repo=/var/git/meuprojeto.git

# Isso vai copiar o conteúdo do push para o seu projeto
git --work-tree=$meuprojeto --git-dir=$git_repo checkout -f

# Esse arquivo é só um bash script. Adicione aqui comandos 
# para executar o seu build, usando as suas ferramentas de
# costume (maven, ant, junit, etc.)

# Exemplo:
cd $meuprojeto
pkill -f meuprojeto-SNAPSHOT
mvn clean package
nohup java -jar target/meuprojeto-SNAPSHOT.jar server meuprojeto.yml > /var/log/java/meuprojeto.log 2>&1 &
```

Aperte `Esc` para sair do modo de edição e `:wq` para salvar o arquivo.

Após sair do vi, conceda permissão de execução a esse arquivo:

```
chmod +x post-receive
```

Pronto. Isso vai copiar os arquivos e rodar o build do seu projeto (e mais tudo o que você escrever para executar).

> **NOTA:** Esse bash acima é só um exemplo. Deve funcionar, mas para rodar em produção, recomendo que você acrescente mais comandos no
>   script ou outros tipos de hook (ver dicas no final da resposta).

---

### Configurando o seu ambiente local:

Agora vá para o seu repositório local, na sua máquina. Dentro da pasta do seu projeto, adicione o seu repositório remoto:

```
git remote add meuprojeto ssh://usuario@xxx.xxx/var/git/meuprojeto.git
```

Substitua `xxx.xxx` pelo IP ou o domínio do seu servidor.

Pronto! Você já pode fazer o push e aproveitar o deploy automático:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Testando deploy automático"
git push meuprojeto master
```

---

### Dicas:

**1) Trabalhando com Diversos repositórios remotos**

Você pode usar a mesma técnica para adicionar diversos repositórios remotos. É uma boa prática você ter um servidor de testes, de homologação e de produção. Então seus pushs ficariam assim:

```
git push testes_meuprojeto master
git push homologacao_meuprojeto master
```

Você também pode configurar o git para usar um desses endereços remotos como padrão, assim:

```
git push -u testes_meuprojeto master
```

e nas próximas vezes que você escrever `git push` sem argumentos, ele vai subir para o seu repositório de testes como padrão.

**2) Mais sobre git hooks**

Existem outros tipos de hooks no git além do post-receive que falei acima, que podem ser usados para diversas tarefas importantes. Para conhecê-los mais a fundo, dê uma olhada nesse site sobre [git hooks](http://githooks.com/) ou veja a [documentação oficial](https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v1/Customizando-o-Git-Hooks-do-Git).

Alguns exemplos do que pode ser feito:

- Checar padrões de código;
- Enviar e-mail pro time avisando do deploy;
- Rodar testes unitários antes de executar o build;
- Um script de rollback caso dê algum problema após o build.

Enfim, espero ter ajudado! =)

Comment: Olá, Rafael. Muito bacana a resposta. Agora entendo como é implementada a rotina de geração de deploy do OpenShift. Uma única lacuna na sua resposta é quanto a questão do deploy automático. Com isso me refiro ao processo de publicar uma aplicação num servido de aplicação como o JBoss. Acho que você confundiu com publicação automática.

Comment: Ops, não percebi que a pergunta era específica do Java. Esse primeiro comando que passei apenas copia os arquivos. Porém, esse arquivo de post-commit é apenas um script Bash, você pode escrever comandos arbitrários nele, como executar um build no ant, por exemplo.

Comment: Você pode, por exemplo, configurar o post-commit para rodar testes unitários e publicar só se passar. Mas isso é assunto para outro post. ;)

Comment: Rafael, acho que sua resposta responde bem a pergunta "Como implementar um processo semelhante a este?" e por isso merece ser aprovada. Para que fique com mais completude seria interessante frisar, deixar mais claro,  a questão da necessidade do script com o uso dos hooks.

Comment: OK, vou editar.

Comment: Feito! Acrescentei um link com a documentação dos git hooks também, caso queira se aprofundar mais no assunto.