# Git, subir códigos diretamente para o servidor

Tags: git, github

Queria saber se é possível uma forma de deixar todos os meus projetos online de forma que eu não fique modificando sempre o meu código para subi-lo ao servidor.

## Vai algumas questões:

- Uso o git, queria usar um branch para cada ambiente de desenvolvimento, neste caso seria a melhor alternativa?
- Agora a cada atualização no código queria subi-lo direto ao servidor com o push(GIT), sem ter de fazer uploads manuais para o servidor. Tipo o github, mas ele não interpreta código PHP, apenas front-end, este o motivo de eu desejar subir direto ao servidor.

---

Não sei se aqui é o melhor lugar para postar isso, mas espero que sim, obrigado!

---

### Atualização

Achei um blog onde o cara ensina, [Link](https://medium.com/@wesleysaraujo/deploy-com-git-configurando-e-executando-um-deploy-automatizado-156e3e1bc374#.3easdunw2)
Vou deixar aberta para quem quiser colocar sua resposta, porém esta pergunta está duplicada, não sei se deveria deletá-la?!

---

@egomesbrandao está falando disso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

## Minha solução

O plano do meu servidor é gratuito, porém ele suporta SSH, mas no meu plano (gratuito) ele está desativado. Então fui neste link ["GitHub git-ftp"](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp) e fiz conforme a documentação.
Já que meu plano não aceita SSH fiz pelo FTP mesmo, porém agora eu não preciso colocar usuário e senha de FTP sempre que for dar update, basta fazer isso(usuario e senha) uma vez e dar um "git push". Esse programinha é meio lento, mas automatizando as tarefas já poupa um tempo bacana!

Obrigado pelas respostas!

Comment: Como é o teu workflow até chegar em produção? Par sugerir algo mais adequado.

Comment: Você diz no sentido de usar o git semelhante ao FTP?

Comment: Isso, git semelhante ao FTP @AndersonCarlosWoss

Comment: Você quer fazer deploy da sua aplicação usando o git?

Comment: Isso tipo o deploy, desculpa por não saber explicar, não sou muito avançado no git. @devsimoes

Comment: Sim, é possível fazer isso, e na minha humilde opinião é muito melhor que usar ftp, mas você vai precisar configurar a conexão ssh no seu servidor, muitos servidores de hospedagens já oferecem essa opção e até mesmo já vêm como a opção de deploy pronta, como é o caso da umbler.com, enfim, um outro usuário já fez uma pergunta parecida com a sua, dê uma olhada:  http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/82475/deploy-autom%C3%A1tico-ap%C3%B3s-git-push

Comment: Me recomendariam este? https://medium.com/@wesleysaraujo/deploy-com-git-configurando-e-executando-um-deploy-automatizado-156e3e1bc374#.3easdunw2 @JonathanFreitas

Comment: Sim, ele está bem detalhado.

Comment: Ah, na hora de criar as pasta *.git uisando o comando mkdir app.git && cd app.git, por questões de segurança, o ideal é que faça isso fora da pasta public ou www, em um diretório onde o usuário não possa acessar.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado! @JonathanFreitas

Comment: @JonathanFreitas tem como fazer isso sem usar SSH ?

Comment: O que você quer fazer é: Apos cada commit seu no repositório, publicar automaticamente a nova versão em um determinado servidor e para cada servidor você deseja utilizar um brench, é isso?

Comment: @Intruso vou dar-lhe um exemplo. Para ambiente de desenvolvimento. usar o branch master, e para a produção "host". Ou pode ser o master para ambos, o que eu quero é acabar com isso de ficar fazendo upload manual no meu servidor. Quero que ao um push ou até mesmo um commit fazer o deploy, o meu plano de hospedagem não me permite acesso ao ssh ;/

Comment: Sim, além do SSH, dá para usar o protocolo FTP com o GIT, com o comando git ftp push, mas para isso, você precisa usar o git-ftp na sua máquina local. http://git-ftp.github.io/git-ftp/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não! Usar branch para cada ambiente não é a melhor alternativa, isso se chama promoção de código; e essa técnica não é mais usada.
A ideia é promover binários ou artefatos gerados em um processo de build. Como o PHP não é uma linguagem que gera binários, o que você irá promover são os artefatos que basicamente serão os mesmos arquivos, porém com algumas peculiaridades.

Imagina que você tenha uma string de conexão de banco de dados. Em um bom pipeline você teria um banco para cada ambiente, para isso teria que ter uma string para cada um, não faz sentido ter mudar o código para cada ambiente. Então usa-se um processo de tokenização no arquivo de configuração para substituir o conteúdo da string para cada ambiente que é feito o deploy. Essa é apenas uma das técnicas, por isso chama-se processo de build e deploy, existem várias tarefas que você irá executar para completar esse processo.

Outra prática seria, ao fazer o push no repositório Git, disparar o processo todo acima, e não colocar um Git no servidor de deploy, é até mesmo um anti-pattern fazer isso.

Para toda essa automação de pipeline existem ferramentas como Trevis CI, Hudson, etc...